# Convert attached pdf to image

Tags: pdf, images

I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere. We have a requirement to convert pdf files that are attached in Attachments to a png or bmp. Are there any apex utilities or such that can be used for this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I don't think SFDC is a good fit for this use case; you're likely to run into execution time limits for all but the simplest PDF files. I think you'd be better served performing this transformation using an external webservice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Jonathan. It looks as if the web service is our only option at this point. I was surprised that there weren't any other viable options. Thanks again.